# Plone 4.3: AttributeError: clear on membrane_tool while updating catalog

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

Recently I have upgraded a plone 3 website to plone 4.3 website. At myhost/projectname/membrane_tool/manage_catalogAdvanced I have tried clear and rebuild also tried update catalog. But they are generating same error as

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 425, in manage_catalogRebuild
Module plone.app.discussion.patches, line 45, in patchedClearFindAndRebuild
Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 287, in manage_catalogClear
Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 102, in clear

AttributeError: clear
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean 'portal_catalog' instead of 'membrane_tool' by any chance? Refs: http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/AttributeError-clear-td6309315.html and http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Plone4-upgrade-and-unsorted-quot-recently-modified-quot-td6353366.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but it's under membrane_tool

Comment: is there an update for membrane required for plone 4.3 that you need to install?

Comment: no. But it is solved after using GET method instead POST in an .pt file. But still don't know why this error appears and gone after using GET instead post. Any ideas?